# How do you set linesize, pagesize, and other environment parameters permanently in Oracle 10g?

Tags: oracle10g, sqlplus

how to set linesize, pagesize permanently in oracle 10g?

Answer (score 15):

Is this for SQL*Plus? If so, these instructions will work:

Create a file (or edit it if it's already there) called glogin.sql in the <ORACLE_HOME>\sqlplus\admin directory 
(ex. C:\Oracle\Ora10g\sqlplus\admin\glogin.sql)

This file will get executed every time you log into SQL*Plus.  You can add settings here, such as "set linesize 1000".  Here are the contents of my file:

glogin.sql:
set linesize 1000

Comment: Where is the glogin.sql file in linux systems?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't answer that anymore! If you found it, please share here! :)

Answer (score -3):

`SELECT (YOUR NEEDS) FROM THE TABLE/VIEW` . BEFORE THAT WILL BE THE:

1. set **pagesize** 60000
2. set **linesize** 144